# using date command in bash script: next occurrence of 3pm

Tags: bash, date

I would like, in epoch time, "the next occurrence of 3pm".

The examples here:
http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Examples-of-date.html

and the manual here:
http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Relative-items-in-date-strings.html#Relative-items-in-date-strings

do not seem to cover this case.

To be clear, if the current date is August 20th at 5pm, I would like this to return the epoch seconds of August 21st at 3pm. If the current date is August 20th at 2pm, I would like this to return the epoch seconds of August 20th at 3pm.

I tried the following but it always returns 3pm of today:

```
date -d "15:00:00" +%s
```

Comment: Somebody should patch the `date -d` expression parser to support a much richer set of temporal primitives.

Comment: The `date` command is independent of `bash`.

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  Why do you need to know "seconds since epoch of next occurrence of a time"?  I'll bet there is a more simple way to approach this.

Comment: @idfah I need "seconds since epoch" because that is the input of the program that I'm using. It's not a big deal because If I have other date formats I can easily convert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cannot edit or comment @paxdiablo answer because of my reputation, so I will write it here:

First of all, it is not going to work. date `+%H` can return numbers that start with a '0'. For example, at 09:00 it will throw this error:

```
bash: [[: 09: value too great for base (error token is "09")
```

So instead of using `+%H` you should use `+%k` or `+%_H` (these two are exactly the same)

Another thing is that I wont suggest using `[[ ]]` for maths. Simply because bash has `(( ))` for that and there are normal operators like `>=` instead of `-ge` argument.

Also, do not use `" "` if you're not working with variables. Use `' '`. This way the code is much clearer and easier to understand.

So, fixed version is here:

```
if (( $(date +%_H) >= 15 )); then
    date -d 'tomorrow 15:00' +%s
else
    date -d '15:00' +%s
fi
```

And here is slightly different version. I prefer this one because it is easier to maintain the code this way.

```
nextHour=15
dateStr="$nextHour:00"
(( $(date +%_H) >= nextHour )) && dateStr="tomorrow $dateStr"
date -d "$dateStr" +%s
```

Good! This is going to work if you don't need exact time. Now, what if you want to work with exact time? Like `15:27`?

The approach is slightly different:

```
nextTime='15:27'
secondsEarly=$(date -d "$nextTime" +%s)
secondsLate=$(date -d "tomorrow $nextTime" +%s)
secondsNow=$(date +%s)
(( secondsEarly > secondsNow )) && echo "$secondsEarly" || echo "$secondsLate"
```

I hope this answers your question. I suggest you to use the last variant.

P.S. Oh, last piece of code does one unneeded operation in cases when early date is used. Here is a slightly optimized code:

```
nextTime='15:27'
secondsEarly=$(date -d "$nextTime" +%s)
(( secondsEarly > $(date +%s) )) && echo "$secondsEarly" || date -d "tomorrow $nextTime" +%s
```

But if I were you I wouldn't use that, because previous code was more readable.

Comment: It is always a good idea to use a more standard syntax like `[` instead of `((` because sometimes portability is required. Good to know about `%_H`... nothing like the hack of paxdiablo though ;p

Comment: @akostadinov Thanks for making a note on portability, but since we're writing in bash, we must use modern bash syntax. I do not agree that using ``test`` in bash is a good idea.

Comment: We need to agree to disagree here ;) if you ever worked on portable software or certification of portable software you would know how weird other unixes are sometimes. There is nothing wrong to use `[` when possible. btw modern linux distros do not use bash for init scripts so portable scrpiting is still needed (I know many switching off scripts to systemd).

Comment: @akostadinov Well, the point is that [[ ]] is more error-proof, so it is suggested for the beginners. It also provides comfortable things that you are used to! Like ``<=`` or ``&&``. If someone is writing an init script then I really hope that they know what they're doing. So, portability is great, but there's no way I would prefer portability over modern bash code style.

Comment: That's what I said. You don't have to deal with portability. If you have a choice between writing a portable code and writing one thing several times, then you would think otherwise ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could always check the hour first with something like:

```
if [[ $(date +1%H) -ge 115 ]] ; then
    date -d "tomorrow 15:00:00" +%s
else
    date -d "15:00:00" +%s
fi
```

The `1` on the front of the date format and the hour `15` is to ensure two possibilities returned from `date +%H` don't get treated as invalid octal numbers (`08` and `09`). That's actually a bit of a kludge so you can use numeric comparisons in conjunction with `date` itself:

```
if [[ $(date +%s) -ge $(date -d "15:00" +%s) ]] ; then
    date -d "tomorrow 15:00" +%s
else
    date -d "15:00" +%s
fi
```

This won't generate numbers beginning with `0` so the octal problem is irrelevant. It will also work with arbitrary times like `13:22:17`.

The following transcript shows this is action:

```
pax> date
Wednesday 21 August  15:46:16 WST 2013

pax> if [[ $(date +%s) -ge $(date -d "15:00" +%s) ]]
...>     then date -d "tomorrow 15:00"
...>     else date -d "15:00"
...> fi
Thursday 22 August  15:00:00 WST 2013

pax> if [[ $(date +%s) -ge $(date -d "16:00" +%s) ]]
...>     then date -d "tomorrow 16:00"
...>     else date -d "16:00"
...> fi
Wednesday 21 August  16:00:00 WST 2013
```

---

Perhaps a better way to do it is with the following function:

```
#!/bin/bash

nexttime() {
    if [[ $(date +%s) -ge $(date -d $1 +%s) ]] ; then
        date -d "tomorrow $1"
    else
        date -d $1
    fi
}

echo $(nexttime $1)
```

When you run that with various options at various times, you can see how it works:

```
pax> date
Wednesday 21 August  15:59:24 WST 2013

pax> qq.sh 16:00
Wednesday 21 August 16:00:00 WST 2013

... waits a few minutes

pax> date
Wednesday 21 August  16:04:51 WST 2013

pax> qq.sh 16:00
Thursday 22 August 16:00:00 WST 2013
```

And, with an arbitrary time, you can see it switch over from today to tomorrow:

```
pax> date ; qq.sh 16:08:32
Wednesday 21 August  16:08:25 WST 2013
Wednesday 21 August 16:08:32 WST 2013

pax> date ; qq.sh 16:08:32
Wednesday 21 August  16:08:28 WST 2013
Wednesday 21 August 16:08:32 WST 2013

pax> date ; qq.sh 16:08:32
Wednesday 21 August  16:08:30 WST 2013
Wednesday 21 August 16:08:32 WST 2013

pax> date ; qq.sh 16:08:32
Wednesday 21 August  16:08:32 WST 2013
Thursday 22 August 16:08:32 WST 2013

pax> date ; qq.sh 16:08:32
Wednesday 21 August  16:08:34 WST 2013
Thursday 22 August 16:08:32 WST 2013
```

Comment: there is a typo +H needs to be `+%H` but can't edit due to stupid rules for 6 chars edit

Comment: This code is NOT going to work. date +%H can return numbers that start with a '0'. Read my answer for more info

Comment: @user2698019: good point, I've adjusted the answer to make that moot.

Comment: @paxdiablo Haha, what a fix :D

Comment: You're right, it's butt-ugly. I'll put in a slightly better one that using `date` itself so as to not worry about the octal issue.

Comment: why do you care about leading zeroes? They don't do harm as far as I see.

Comment: @akostadinov: because they're treated as octal, so that `if [[ 09 -eq 9 ]] ; then echo yes ; fi` gives you the error `bash: [[: 09: value too great for base (error token is "09")` because `8` and `9` are not octal digits.

Answer (score 1):

### Use a Small If/Else Statement

There are other ways, but one way is to simply compare the current time with today's target time to see if *now* is earlier or later than the target time. For example:

```
# Store some timestamps for comparison.
_now=$(date +%s)
_3pm_today=$(date -d "15:00:00 today" +%s)
_3pm_tomorrow=$(date -d "15:00:00 tomorrow" +%s)

# If target time is in the future, show stores today's value. Else store 
# tomorrow's value instead.
if [[ $_3pm_today -ge $_now ]]; then
    date=$_3pm_today
else
    date=$_3pm_tomorrow
fi
```